# como puedo hacer varias entradas y salidas desde la terminal y guardar las respuestas en variables? en javascrpit nodejs metodo readline

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Escribir el algoritmo que permite calcular la nota correspondiente al primer parcial de “análisis” para un estudiante cualquiera. Se debe considerar que hay dos talleres y un quiz, que en conjunto valen un 30% de la nota y el resto (70%) corresponde a la nota del examen parcial, entradas y salidas por la terminal

const readline = require('readline');

function calcularNota(){
console.log('\nEjercicio #3\n')

```
let taller1;
let taller2;
let quiz;
let parcial;
let nota1 = (taller1+taller2+quiz)/3;//sacamos el promedio
nota1 = nota1 * 0.3; //equivale a el 30%
let nota2 = parcial * 0.7; //equivale al 70%
let notaFinal = nota1 + nota2

let interfazCaptura = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout 
});

/*process.stdout.write('Ingrese la nota del taller 1: ');
process.stdin.on('data', function (data){
    taller1 = data.toString().trim();
    process.stdout.write(`nota1 30% taller 1, taller 2 y quiz: ${taller1} \n`);
    process.exit();
});*/

interfazCaptura.question('Ingrese nota taller 2: ', function(respuesta){
    taller2 = respuesta;
    
    interfazCaptura.setPrompt('taller 1: ');
    interfazCaptura.prompt();
    //taller1 = respuesta;
    

    interfazCaptura.close();
    
})


/*let taller1=5;
let taller2=4;
let quiz=3;
let parcial=4;
let nota1 = (taller1+taller2+quiz)/3;//sacamos el promedio
nota1 = nota1 * 0.3; //equivale a el 30%
let nota2 = parcial * 0.7; //equivale al 70%
let notaFinal = nota1 + parcial
console.log('esta es la nota de analisis ' + notaFinal)*/
```

};
calcularNota()

Answer (score 0):

```
logre encontrar otra solución con readline-sync se debe instalar npm install dejo el código funciona perfectamente
```

```
    const inputReadLine = require('readline-sync');
    let taller1 = parseInt(inputReadLine.question("Ingresa la nota del taller 1: 
    "));
    let taller2 = parseInt(inputReadLine.question("Ingresa la nota del taller 2: 
    "));
    let quiz = parseInt(inputReadLine.question("Ingresa la nota del quiz: "));
    let parcial = inputReadLine.question("Ingresa la nota del parcial: ");
    let nota1 = (taller1+taller2+quiz)/3;//sacamos el promedio
    nota1 = nota1 * 0.3; //equivale a el 30%
    let nota2 = parcial * 0.7; //equivale al 70%
    let notaFinal = nota1 + nota2

    console.log(`El 30% de la nota finalque equivale a taller 1, taller 2 y el 
    quiz es de: ${nota1}`);
    console.log(`El 70% de la nota final equivale al parcial es de: ${nota2}`);
    console.log(`La nota final es de: ${notaFinal}`);
```

Comment: si saben de otra solución les agradezco